# Can a PHP Web Service return two or more arrays?

Tags: php, web-services, ios

I'm working on web service which is supposed to return two arrays to my iOS application, is this possible with one PHP class in the web service development?

Comment: You mean a multidimensional array?

Comment: No, actually two array independant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, however it will require some creativity. My recommendation is that you wrap your two arrays in another array, and return that single array to your iOS application.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$array1 = array("1","2","3");
$array2 = array("4","4","6");
$array3 = array($array1, $array2);

return $array3;
```

Comment: Hi, but in my case, array1 doesn't has the same length of array2, for example, array1 has 30 items, however array2 has 90, besides, they havn't the same elements type, ayyar1(numeric), array2(varchar):(

Comment: @Malek: From the web service side it doesn't matter how many elements are in each array nor what type of data they contain. PHP is not type-sensitive when creating arrays.

Comment: to add on to my previous comment, `$array3` is an array containing two distinct `array` objects. So, the contents of each of `$array1` and `$array2` are independent of one another.

Comment: ok, last question, from the iOS side, is it easy to parse the items of the two arrays separetly or i will have problems ? thx

Comment: I will have to defer to someone who knows more than I about iOS programming, however my intuition is that it should not be difficult.

Comment: you could use json, and output something like `{"keyone":[your first array],"keytwo":[your second array]}` and then in your ios code, you handle it as a dictionary of arrays

Answer (score 1):

it can return one array consisting of two array but not two array differently

Comment: Hi, so what could be the alternative for my case ??

Comment: you should return one array consisting two array `return array($array1, $array2);`

Comment: but in the side of the iOS application, it will be considered as one array and i won't be able to parse the two arrays

Answer (score 1):

Check out this questions:

- [Returning An Array of Objects in PHP Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459955/returning-an-array-of-objects-in-php-web-service)
- [PHP Web Service - Same call: Multiple records = array, 1 record=single object - How to work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946319/php-web-service-same-call-multiple-records-array-1-record-single-object-h)
- [Jquery and Web services: Can I pass more than one array in data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712009/jquery-and-web-services-can-i-pass-more-than-one-array-in-data-attribute)